# How can I create help tags for vim plugins from packages?

Tags: package-management, vim, vimrc

I have installed the `vim-latexsuite` and `vim-outliner` packages, which are addons for vim. Both come with documentation files, that are installed into the `/usr/share/vim/addons/doc directory`. Issuing the 'help' command from within vim, the documentation is not availabe, because it had not been installed properly. This might apply to other addons as well.

How can I create the help tags for these addons that I expected to be created by the installation routine?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem in two steps.

1. Since vim had not been able to generate the required index from the compressed documentation, I extracted these files before re-running the indexer. As vim is able to deal with compressed documentation, I removed the extracted documents and adjusted the filenames of the index accordingly.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#set -x
set -e

umask 077 
TMPTAGS=$(mktemp --tmpdir "`basename "$0"`.XXXXXXXXXXXX")
trap "rm -f '$TMPTAGS'" EXIT

declare -r AWK_SCRIPT='{ if( $2 in files ) $2=$2".gz"; print }'

helptags(){
        # extract zipped helpfiles and remember filenames
        local -i I=0 
        local -a TXT 
        for ZIP in `find . -xtype f \( -name '*.txt.gz' -o -name '*.??x.gz' \)`; do
                T=${ZIP%.gz}
                if [ -n "$T" ]; then
                        TXT[$((I++))]=$T
                        zcat "$ZIP" >"$T"
                fi
        done
        # generate tagfiles
        vim -c 'helptags .' +q
        # point tags to the zipped helpfiles
        local AWK_BEGIN="BEGIN { OFS=FS; "
        while [ $((I--)) -gt 0 ]; do
                AWK_BEGIN+="files[\"`basename "${TXT[$I]}"`\"]; "
        done
        AWK_BEGIN+='}'
        for T in `find . -xtype f \( -name 'tags' -o -name 'tags-??' \)`; do
                awk -F '\t' "$AWK_BEGIN $AWK_SCRIPT" "$T" >"$TMPTAGS"
                mv -f "$TMPTAGS" "$T"
        done
        # remove unzipped helpfiles
        for T in "${TXT[@]}"; do
                rm -f "$T"
        done
}

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        if [ -d "$1" ]; then
                pushd "$1" >/dev/null
                helptags
                popd >/dev/null
        else
                printf '*** Invalid argument: %s\n' "$1" >&2 
        fi
        shift
done
```

2. Finally, I have appended `/usr/share/vim/addons` to the `runtimpath` variables in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim` and `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny`.